# Application insights Dependency failures due to Table storage concurrency exception

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-application-insights, azure-table-storage

I've a background process which updates data in table storage, in certain conditions due to concurrency, updates to the table storage fails with status code:409 "pre condition failed" and it is handled in the back ground process, even though it is handled in the code, this is appearing in the App insights Dependencies as a failure. Is there a better way to handle these exceptions so that it doesn't appear as a failure, since it is handled in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure Table Storage and Application Insights in your code, you may get some conflicts errors like 409.

If you are using **`Azure.Data.Table`** **SDK** and you are checking if the table is exist or not if not create it.

In this case **CreateIfNotExists()** the SDK simply try to create a new table and it hides the error if the table is available. This you are not noticed in your code you may get the dependency failure in Application Insights.  Application insights will catch this information in a log.

To avoid the dependency failure, you can follow the below steps

1. Catch the type of Configure events in Application Insights
2. Manually check before your script runs in a background if the table exists or not before creating it.

#### References

1. [Failing Dependencies from Application Insights logging](https://zimmergren.net/excluding-failing-dependencies-from-application-insights-logging/)
2. [Conflict Error while using Application Insights and Table Storage](https://medienstudio.net/development-en/application-insights-azure-table-storage-createifnotexists-errors/)